# Does VS2010 use csc.exe / vbc.exe (directly or indirectly) to compile relevant projects?

Tags: compiler-construction, visual-studio-2010, csc, vbc

Pretty much as the title suggests.

I can't find any proof that DevEnv.exe actually calls these at any point.

Comment: Have a look at process explorer when doing a build- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Also, here's an interesting link: http://blogs.msdn.com/ed_maurer/archive/2008/06/11/a-tale-of-two-compilers.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio uses an [in-process compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2005/11/10/489666.aspx) for C# compilation. I would guess the same is true for VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `targets` files - you will see that the compilers are referenced in the relevant `targets` file.

These files are what MSBuild uses to determine what and how to build a project (when using F5 or Build Project).